# Visual Studio Emulator for Android memory minimum?

Tags: memory, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, android-emulator

I'm using the VS emulator for Android with Visual Studio 2015 Community (Update 3). When I run a Xamarin project this error displays:

> The emulator is unable to verify that the virtual machine is running: Not enough memory is available to start an emulator that uses 3072 MB of startup RAM.

OK, from this page https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt228280.aspx we see the system requirements where we need Hyper-V support and 6 GB or more of RAM.

My laptop has <strike>4GB</strike> **8GB** RAM plus swap space. When I allocate 3072 MB to the virtual machine through the Hyper-V Manager, the emulator starts but running and debugging is slow, of course because now there's only 1GB of RAM for VS and whatever else is running. (Yes, I try to minimize other RAM usage...)

So I wanted to reduce the footprint of the VM. However, and this is the common mistake some people are making: Reducing the size of the VM doesn't reduce the amount of memory that VS wants, it only reduces the *available* memory. And if the available memory is less than what VS wants we get that error.

So my questions are:

1) Can we modify a config somewhere to reduce the amount of RAM that VS wants in a virtual machine?

2) Is there an XDE.exe command-line somewhere that gets used where we can set the memory?

3) And ultimately, can anyone provide a good reason why an emulator *requires* 3GB or more of RAM? I don't want to suffocate the execution of the environment but I don't want it to take a lot more than it really needs either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C:\Users[YourUserName]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudioEmulator\Android\Containers\Local\Devices

Just head to this URL and you will find the files
Now you will just have to open each one of them and change this line content, replacing the  value with “1024”:

Comment: I haven't worked in that environment for a while and can't verify your answer. However, it *is* an answer, and for that you get the flag. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I open "Hyper-V Manager" and edit it's memory in setting Pane. So easy